# JAXB: is typesafeEnumMemberName="generateName" customizable?

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf-codegen-plugin

I was having some issues to import a WSDL that have a XSD with numeric enums.

Adding *typesafeEnumMemberName="generateName"* to my global bindings solved it, but the generated enum items are meaningless...

Example:

```
<simpleType name="dm_UF">
    <restriction base="string">
        <length value="2"/>
        <enumeration value="50"/>
        <enumeration value="51"/>
        <enumeration value="52"/>
        <enumeration value="53"/>
        <enumeration value="98"/>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>


@XmlEnumValue("50")
VALUE_24("50"),

@XmlEnumValue("51")
VALUE_25("51"),

@XmlEnumValue("52")
VALUE_26("52"),

@XmlEnumValue("53")
VALUE_27("53"),

@XmlEnumValue("98")
VALUE_28("98");
```

Instead of **VALUE_ + itemPosition**, I'd like to have **VALUE_ + itemValue** to avoid the developer making some mistake.

Changing the XSD is not an option, since there it's a government standard and there are lots of other numeric enums, some with thousands of items...

I'm using the cxf-codegen-plugin version 3.1.5 + krasa-jaxb-tools 1.4

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the **fromValue** method that is generated with the enums.

So instead of doing `GeneratedEnum.VALUE_<<itemPosition>>`,

I can do `GeneratedEnum.fromValue("<<itemValue>>")`.